# bitbake nodejs - ERROR: nodejs-7.10.0-r1.4 do_configure: Execution

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I can't install nodejs using the meta-nodejs library on qemux86-64.
bitbake nodejs gives the following error

> Initialising tasks: 100%
> |########################################################################################################################################################################|
> Time: 0:00:05 Sstate summary: Wanted 7 Found 0 Missed 7 Current 780
> (0% match, 99% complete) NOTE: Executing Tasks ERROR:
> nodejs-7.10.0-r1.4 do_configure: Execution of
> '/home/user/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/nodejs/7.10.0-r1.4/temp/run.do_configure.68465'
> failed with exit code 127: /usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or
> directory WARNING: exit code 127 from a shell command.
>
> ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in:
> /home/user/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/nodejs/7.10.0-r1.4/temp/log.do_configure.68465
> Log data follows: | DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure |
> /usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory | WARNING: exit code
> 127 from a shell command. | ERROR: Execution of
> '/home/user/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/nodejs/7.10.0-r1.4/temp/run.do_configure.68465'
> failed with exit code 127: | /usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or
> directory | WARNING: exit code 127 from a shell command. | ERROR: Task
> (/home/user/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-nodejs/recipes-devtools/nodejs/nodejs_7.10.0.bb:do_configure)
> failed with exit code '1' NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 2022 tasks of
> which 2016 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
>
> Summary: 1 task failed:
> /home/user/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-nodejs/recipes-devtools/nodejs/nodejs_7.10.0.bb:do_configure
> Summary: There was 1 WARNING message shown. Summary: There was 1 ERROR
> message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.

I installed python on both the host and on the target

can someone help me?

Comment: See https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/3911

Comment: meta-nodejs is outdated, use nodejs from meta-oe

Comment: It work with meta-oe .Thanks @Florian Berndl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

meta-nodejs is outdated, use nodejs from meta-oe